# OpenCart Menu a.clicked shows and disappears

Tags: html, css, opencart

Using OC v1.5.6.4
**I wish to keep css state for header menu as Clicked after clicked**

I have this going as menu:

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Store</a>
        <div>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="#">Man</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Woman</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
   </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

With **css** so:

```
#m > ul > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#m > ul > li:hover > a {
    color:#000 !important;
}
#m > ul >  li > a.clicked {
    color: #823428;
    border-bottom: #823428 2px solid !important;;
}
#m > ul > li > div > ul > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I have jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("a").click(function(e) {
    $("a", $("#menu")).each(function () {
        if( $(this).hasClass("clicked") )
            $(this).removeClass("clicked");
    });

    $(this).addClass("clicked");
    });
});
```

When link is clicked before releasing mouse button it does turn to a.selected
But after mouse click released it does not save class state.

What am I doing wrong?? Is it the page reloading??
Example:

[example - not working](http://newebgen.com/index.php?route=common/home)

[jsfiddle - working great](http://jsfiddle.net/jadeye26/HDcqr/33/)

Comment: First: In your jQuery above, you are calling the function on `#menu` which isn't anywhere in your CSS or HTML. If you change that to `#m` it should work. Also, if you are trying to keep the menu open instead of going to a link, you'll need to add `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: @disinfor: thanx! #menu was my mistake...keep the menu open??? what do you mean?

Comment: So what you want is when someone clicks "Store", once they are taken to that page, the link will remain underlined?

Comment: Well, you need to use a server side language (PHP) or jQuery on the page to read the URL to add the class. However, there is an extension for OpenCart to add a class to the navigation so you can style it with CSS http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=6500

Answer (score 1):

After adding the *working fiddle* (which is not working at all - the anchors have no `href` value provided, thus the *redirect* takes no effect, and the sub-tree does not work even in Your fiddle) I now can see what are You trying to achieve.

And this cannot be done before (nor during) the `onclick` event, but after the page is reloaded. You need to get the current URL and manually (either by JS or PHP) add a class `clicked` to the list item that has that URL in it's `href` attribute... Clear?

Comment: It's the same solution I came up with (I deleted my answer). Jadeye wants the underline to be persistent on the page you are viewing. For instance if you are on the "Store" page, "Store" will be underlined.

Answer (score 0):

Never did get to post the solution so here goes:

JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    setNavigation();
});
function setNavigation() {
    var currentHref = window.location.href;

    $("#menu a").each(function () {
        console.log("currentHref = " + currentHref);
        console.log("window.location.href = " +  window.location.href);
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        console.log("this_href = " + href);
        if (currentHref === href) {
            console.log("adding ACTIVE" + $(this).attr('href'));
            $(this).addClass('clicked');
        }
    });
}
```

Related css:

```
#menu > ul > li > a.clicked {
    color: #823428;
    border-bottom: #823428 2px solid !important;
}
```

What this does is save the clicked URL and compares it to the redirected URL - if equal then the HREF is assigned the `click class` defined by the css.

[working_Example](http://oliverge-leather.com/)